# Why does archive utility always expand into the 'downloads' folder regardless of where the file is?

Tags: finder, archive, archive-utility

The title sums it up. For as long as I can remember if you open an archive, it expands into the current folder. Recently they all started going to my 'Downloads' folder.

I figured there's a setting so I checked but it's set up correctly (see image). Thanks in advance!

*2018 15in mbp, Catalina 10.15.3*

[image: Screenshot of my archive utility settings]

Comment: Have you tried setting those settings to any other random folder. Reboot and setting it back?

Comment: Are you sure it's Archive Utility doing the expanding, and not some alternate program?